# MongoDB query nested document fields simultaneously

Tags: mongodb, nested-documents

Having document in collection `test` as follow:

```
{a:2, list:[{lang:"en", value:"Mother"}, {lang:"de", value:"Mutter"}] }
```

When I query:

```
db.test.find({"list.lang":"de", "list.value": "Mother" })
```

I'm expecting to get nothing, but on reason that exist document with 2 nested entries that satisfies total condition MongoDB resolves `{a:2}`

How to fix query to retrieve only documents where both inner fields satisfies to specified condition simultaneously?

Comment: I can think of a query that uses `$all` as `db.test.find({
    "list": {
        "$all": [{"lang":"de", "value": "Mother" }]
    }
})`

Comment: What about [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) `db.test.find({ "list": { "$elemMatch": {"lang":"de", "value": "Mother" } } })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
db.test.find({ "list": { "$elemMatch": {"lang":"de", "value": "Mother" } } })
```

Using [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/):

```
db.test.find({ "list": { "$all": [{"lang":"de", "value": "Mother" }] } })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What of this cases use the indexes?